# Docker image format

Tags: docker, packer, openembedded, yocto

I would like to build a Docker image without docker itself. I have looked at [Packer](http://www.packer.io/docs/builders/docker.html, but it requires that Docker be installed on the builder host.

I have looked at the [Docker Registry API documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/registry_api/#image) but this information doesn't appear to be there.

I guess that the image is simply a tarball, but I would like to see a complete specification of the format, i.e. what exact format is required and whether there are any metadata files required. I could attempt downloading an image from the registry and look what's inside, but there is no information on how to fetch the image itself.

The idea of my project is to implement a script that creates an image from artifacts I have compiled, and uploads it to the registry. I would like to use OpenEmbedded for this purpose, essentially this would be an extension to Bitbake.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After reading [James Coyle's blog](http://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/1512-export-and-import-a-docker-image-between-nodes), I figured that `docker save` and `docker load` commands are what I need.

```
> docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
progrium/consul     latest              e9fe5db22401        11 days ago         25.81 MB
> docker save e9fe5db22401 | tar x
> ls e9fe5db22401*
VERSION  json  layer.tar
```

The `VERSION` file contains only `1.0`, and `json` contains quite a lot of information:

```
{
  "id": "e9fe5db224015ddfa5ee9dbe43b414ecee1f3108fb6ed91add11d2f506beabff",
  "parent": "68f9e4929a4152df9b79d0a44eeda042b5555fbd30a36f98ab425780c8d692eb",
  "created": "2014-08-20T17:54:30.98176344Z",
  "container": "3878e7e9b9935b7a1988cb3ebe9cd45150ea4b09768fc1af54e79b224bf35f26",
  "container_config": {
    "Hostname": "7f17ad58b5b8",
    "Domainname": "",
    "User": "",
    "Memory": 0,
    "MemorySwap": 0,
    "CpuShares": 0,
    "Cpuset": "",
    "AttachStdin": false,
    "AttachStdout": false,
    "AttachStderr": false,
    "PortSpecs": null,
    "ExposedPorts": {
      "53/udp": {},
      "8300/tcp": {},
      "8301/tcp": {},
      "8301/udp": {},
      "8302/tcp": {},
      "8302/udp": {},
      "8400/tcp": {},
      "8500/tcp": {}
    },
    "Tty": false,
    "OpenStdin": false,
    "StdinOnce": false,
    "Env": [
      "HOME=/",
      "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
      "SHELL=/bin/bash"
    ],
    "Cmd": [
      "/bin/sh",
      "-c",
      "#(nop) CMD []"
    ],
    "Image": "68f9e4929a4152df9b79d0a44eeda042b5555fbd30a36f98ab425780c8d692eb",
    "Volumes": {
      "/data": {}
    },
    "WorkingDir": "",
    "Entrypoint": [
      "/bin/start"
    ],
    "NetworkDisabled": false,
    "OnBuild": [
      "ADD ./config /config/"
    ]
  },
  "docker_version": "1.1.2",
  "author": "Jeff Lindsay <progrium@gmail.com>",
  "config": {
    "Hostname": "7f17ad58b5b8",
    "Domainname": "",
    "User": "",
    "Memory": 0,
    "MemorySwap": 0,
    "CpuShares": 0,
    "Cpuset": "",
    "AttachStdin": false,
    "AttachStdout": false,
    "AttachStderr": false,
    "PortSpecs": null,
    "ExposedPorts": {
      "53/udp": {},
      "8300/tcp": {},
      "8301/tcp": {},
      "8301/udp": {},
      "8302/tcp": {},
      "8302/udp": {},
      "8400/tcp": {},
      "8500/tcp": {}
    },
    "Tty": false,
    "OpenStdin": false,
    "StdinOnce": false,
    "Env": [
      "HOME=/",
      "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
      "SHELL=/bin/bash"
    ],
    "Cmd": [],
    "Image": "68f9e4929a4152df9b79d0a44eeda042b5555fbd30a36f98ab425780c8d692eb",
    "Volumes": {
      "/data": {}
    },
    "WorkingDir": "",
    "Entrypoint": [
      "/bin/start"
    ],
    "NetworkDisabled": false,
    "OnBuild": [
      "ADD ./config /config/"
    ]
  },
  "architecture": "amd64",
  "os": "linux",
  "Size": 0
}
```

The `layer.tar` file appears to be empty. So inspected the parent, and the grandparent, both contained no file in their `layer.tar` files.

So assuming that 4.0K is the standard size for an empty tarball:

```
 for layer in $(du -hs */layer.tar | grep -v 4.0K | cut -f2)
 do (echo $layer:;tar tvf $layer)
 done
```

To see that these contain simple incremental changes to the filesystem.

So one conclusion is that it's probably best to just use Docker to build the image and push it the registry, just as Packer does.

The way to build an image from scratch is [described in the docs](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/baseimages/).

It turns out that `docker import - scratch` doesn't care about what's in the tarball. I simply  assumes that is the rootfs.

```
> touch foo
> tar c foo | docker import - scratch
02bb6cd70aa2c9fbaba37c8031c7412272d804d50b2ec608e14db054fc0b9fab
> docker save 02bb6cd70aa2c9fbaba37c8031c7412272d804d50b2ec608e14db054fc0b9fab | tar x
> ls 02bb6cd70aa2c9fbaba37c8031c7412272d804d50b2ec608e14db054fc0b9fab/
VERSION  json  layer.tar
> tar tvf 02bb6cd70aa2c9fbaba37c8031c7412272d804d50b2ec608e14db054fc0b9fab/layer.tar    
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2014-09-01 13:46 ./
-rw-r--r-- 500/500           0 2014-09-01 13:46 foo
```

In terms of OpenEmbedded integration, it's probably best to build the `rootfs` tarball, which is something Yocto provides out of the box, and use the [official Python library](https://github.com/docker/docker-py) to import the rootfs tarball with `import_image(src='rootfs.tar', repository='scratch')` and then push it private registry method.

This is not the most elegant solution, but that's how it would have to work at the moment. Otherwise one probably can just manage and deploy `rootfs` revisions in their own way, and just use `docker import` on the target host, which still won't be a nice fit, but is somewhat simple.

Answer (score 17):

The Docker image format is specified here: https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/image/spec/v1.md

The simplest possible image is a tar file containing the following:

```
repositories
uniqid/VERSION
uniqid/json
uniqid/layer.tar
```

Where VERSION contains `1.0`, layer.tar contains the chroot contents and json/repositories are JSON files as specified in the spec above.

The resulting tar can be loaded into docker via `docker load < image.tar`