# Are Dockerfiles stored on my machine?

Tags: docker

When I run the command:

```
docker run dockerinaction/hello_world
```

The first time the following scenario plays out:

[image]

The `dockerinaction/hello_world` [`Dockerfile`](https://hub.docker.com/r/dockerinaction/hello_world/~/dockerfile/) can be seen below:

```
FROM busybox:latest
CMD ["echo", "hello world"]
```

So from the wording:

> Docker searches Docker Hub for the image

There are several things I'm curious about:

- Is the *image* `dockerinaction/hello_world`?
- Does this *image* reference another *image* named `busybox:latest`?
- What about the `Dockerfile` is that on my machine somewhere?

Comment: I think a docker image does not include the Dockerfile that built it. But it does refer to the image it is based on. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583038/docker-image-format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answers to each bulleted question, in corresponding order:

- Yes, the *image* is `dockerinaction/hello_world`.
- Yes, the image does reference `busybox:latest`, and builds upon it.
- No, the Dockerfile is not stored on your machine. The `docker run` command is downloading a compressed version of the built Docker image that it found on Docker Hub. In some ways, you can think of the Dockerfile as the source code and the built image as the binary.

---

If you wanted to, you could write your own Dockerfile with the following contents:

```
FROM busybox:latest
CMD ["echo", "hello world"]
```

Then, in the directory containing that file (named `Dockerfile`), you could:

```
$ docker build -t my-hello-world:latest .
$ docker run my-hello-world:latest
```

The `docker build` command builds the Dockerfile, which in this case *is* stored on your machine. The built Docker image is tagged as `my-hello-world:latest`, and is only available on your machine (where it was built) unless you `push` it somewhere. You can run the built image from your machine by referring to the tag in the `docker run` command, as in the second line above.